# Python 3.3.2 - Sorting a List, While Disregarding Vowels

Tags: sorting, python-3.x

I am creating a program that sorts a list (Just like `list.sort()`) but it won't count vowels. Here is what I mean:

I have a list of... `['acd', 'ibc', 'ebb', 'zzaeib']` or something similar. A normal sort program would give this as the result: `['acd', 'ebb', 'ibc', 'zzaeib']`. My sort will need to disregard the vowels, sort it, and the put the vowels back in and return the resulting list. For example, it would see the list above as `['cd', 'bc', 'bb', 'zzb']`. It would then sort it (`['bb', 'bc', 'cd', 'zzb']`) and put the vowels back in (`['ebb', 'ibc', 'acd', 'zzaeib']`).

Here are the differences:

Normal sort: `['acd', 'ebb', 'ibc', 'zzaeib']`

Custom sort: `['ebb', 'ibc', 'acd', 'zzaeib']`

I know I can use the key feature of sort (`list.sort(key=whatever_key)`), but I cannot see a way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Rob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know I can use the key feature of sort

Yep, you were almost there.

```
import re
new_list = sorted(l, key=lambda s: re.sub('[aioue]', '', s))
```